# How to create efficient map system?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance

i have a map system (grid) for my website. I have defined 40000 'fields' on a grid. Each field has a XY value (for x(1-200) and y(1-200)) and a unique identifier: fieldid(1-40000).

I have a viewable area of 16x9 fields. When the user visits `website.com/fieldid/422` it displays 16x9 fields starting with fieldid 422 in the upperleft corner. This obviously follows the XY system, which means the field in the second row, right below #422 is #622.

The user should be able to navigate Up, Down, Left and Right (meaning increment/decrement the X or Y value accordingly). I have a function which converts XY values to fieldids and vice-versa.

Everything good so far, I can:

1. Reload the entire page when a user clicks a navigate button (got this)
2. Send an ajax-request and get a jsonstring with the new 16x9 fields (got this)

> **But I want to build in some sort of caching system so that the data sent back from the server can be minimized after the first load. This would probably mean only sending new 'rows' or 'columns' of fields and storing them in somesort of javascript multidimensional array bigger then the 16x9 used for displaying. But I can't figure it out. Can somebody assist?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible solutions.

1 If you use ajax to get new tiles and do not reload entire page very often, you may just use an object that holds the contents of each tile, using unique tile ids as keys, like:

```
var mapCache = { 
    '1' : "tile 1 data",
    '2' : "tile 2 data"
    //etc.
}
```

When the user request new tiles, first check if you have them in your object (you know which tiles will be needed for given area), then download only what you need and add new key/value pairs to the cache. Obviously all cached data will disappear as soon as the page is reloaded by user.

2 If you reload the page for each request you might split your tiles into separate javascript "files". It doesn't really matter how it would be implemented on the server -  static files like tile1.js, tile2.js etc, or dynamic script (probably with some server-side cache) like tile.php?id=1, tile.php?id=2 etc. What's important is that the server sends proper HTTP headers and makes it possible for the browser to cache these requests. So when a page containing some 144 tiles is requested you have 144 <script /> elements, each one containing data for one tile and each one will be stored in browser's cache. This solution makes sense only if there's lot of data for each tile and data doesn't change on the server very often, or/and there's significant cost of tile generation/trasfer.

Answer (score 1):

You could just have an array of 40,000 references.  Basically, empty array elements don't take up a lot of room until you actually put something in them (its one of the advantages of a dynamically typed language).  Javascript doesn't know if you are going to put an int or an object into an array element, so it doesn't allocate the elements until yo put something in them.  So to summarize, just put them in an array - that simple!

Alternatively, if you don't want the interpreter to allocate 40,000 NULLs at start, you could use a dictionary method, with the keys being the 1 in 40,000 array indices.  Now the unused elements don't even get allocated.  Though if you are going to eventually fill a substantial portion of the map, the dictionary method is much less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Have a single associative array, which initially starts out with zero values.

If the user visits, say, grid 32x41y, you set a value for the array like this:

```
if (!(visitedGrids.inArray('32'))
{
   visitedGrids['32'] = {}
}
visitedGrids['32']['41'] = data;
```

(This is pseudo-code; I haven't checked the syntax.)

Then you can check to see if the user has visited the appropriate grid coordinates by seeing if there is a value in the associative array.